# How do you get KUDU to use MSBuild 15

Tags: azure, msbuild, kudu

```
Microsoft.Net.Compilers is only supported on MSBuild v15.0 and above
```

whatever the auto detect tooling is for KUDU, it always selects 14

is there a way for force it to select 15?

Answer (score 13):

Add an app-setting for your Web App:

`MSBUILD_PATH` with the value `%MSBUILD_15_DIR%\msbuild.exe`

This will be picked up by the default deploy script.

Comment: After trying this solution several times with no success, I did find out this app setting key has to be added BEFORE the deployment center options are completed/saved.  Adding the keys after your repo is already connected will not work.

Comment: It's picked up by the Kudu build script, so you need to redeploy (or indeed set it before you first deploy).

Comment: This solution worked perfect for me. I had to add the app settings and then I redeploy the failed deployment.

Answer (score 3):

msbuild 15 is not used by default. You can use it, with a little modification to your Kudu script.

Here is an example using msbuild 15 for restore, build and publish*.

```
:: 1. Restore nuget packages
call :ExecuteCmd nuget.exe restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\BACON.sln" -MSBuildPath "%MSBUILD_15_DIR%"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2. Build and publish
call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_15_DIR%\MSBuild.exe" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\BACON.WEB.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration=Release /p:publishurl="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

* *change `BACON.sln` & `BACON.WEB.csproj` to your project file names*

Answer (score 2):

The msbuild 15 is now available in Azure, however it's not default you need to add a custom deployment script to  override Kudu's project detection logic .

As **watashiSHUN** described you could add something like this:

```
nuget restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\{SolutionPath}"
"%MSBUILD_PATH%" {MSBuildArguments}
```

And here is the [template](https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduScript/blob/master/lib/templates/deploy.batch.aspnet.wap.template) and the [issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2350#issuecomment-328413838) in the github.