# Can we use MSBuild 16 on an Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, which is using MSBuild 16. On Azure, a web app seems to be using MSBuild 14 by default. Looking at this question, [How do you get KUDU to use MSBuild 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621822/how-do-you-get-kudu-to-use-msbuild-15), it seems we can force the Azure web app to use MSBuild 15. Do Azure web apps support MSBuild 16 yet? And how can we tell if this is so using the command line in Kudu, or some other direct method? (I can't even find any announcements about this.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for raising the issue. This is currently not supported. Are you using .NET core by any chance?

Comment: No, but I'd like to migrate some projects over if it's easy enough.