# How to specify MSBuild version in Azure

Tags: msbuild, c#-7.3, azure-appservice

I have a project that build locally but not when deployed in azure using github + kudu integration.

It complains about the C# version being 7.3

If I manually change the autogenerated deploy script, it solves the issue.

I change the following (in Azure)

```
D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd

****** FROM ******

IF DEFINED MSBUILD_PATH goto MsbuildPathDefined
SET MSBUILD_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
:MsbuildPathDefined

****** TO ******

IF DEFINED MSBUILD_PATH goto MsbuildPathDefined
SET MSBUILD_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
:MsbuildPathDefined
SET MSBUILD_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild-15.9.21.664\MSBuild\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSbuild
```

i.e. I just force it to use MSbuild15

My immediate problem is solved, but it feels like a hack. Is there a way to specify the msbuild version properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this as a guide:

[How do you get KUDU to use MSBuild 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621822/how-do-you-get-kudu-to-use-msbuild-15)

the MSBUILD_PATH is set in the app "configuration" -> "New application setting" (click the +) and then enter

Name: MSBUILD_PATH

Value: %MSBUILD_15_DIR%\msbuild.exe

and check the "Deployment slot setting"

validate by opening powershell in the kudu interface and running:

```
PS D:\home> echo $env:MSBUILD_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Kudo environment should have msbuild variables for each version:

```
D:\home>set msbuild
MSBUILD_15_DIR=D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild-15.9.21.664\MSBuild\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
MSBUILD_16_DIR=D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild-16.4\MSBuild\Current\Bin
MSBUILD_PATH=D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Comment: How do I specify a specific version of msbuild for azure to use, apart from editing the deploy.cmd directly?

Comment: How are you generating the deploy script?

Comment: It is done by azure somehow: I have setup github integration using Kudu, the logs says this with regards to the deploy.cmd:

Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --aspWAP "D:\home\site\repository\Fx\Fx.csproj" --solutionFile "D:\home\site\repository\PDFRipper.sln"').